# Pulling Data Out of A ComboBox

Tags: vba

I have a ComboBox that is being populated by a table, but when I have my ComboBox populated I have it concatenated with some formatting.

```
Do
    strValue = "Loc: " & .Fields(0).Value & " Weight : " & .Fields(1).Value

    cbAlloys.AddItem strValue
    rsDB1.MoveNext

Loop Until rsDB1.EOF
```

So now that it's like this I need to take just the weight value and output it without anything but the weight number.

I tried this:

```
siBinWeightDescription.Value = cbBinAndWeight.Value
siBinWeightDescription.Value = InStr(6, cbBinAndWeight.Value)
```

But, later realized that `Instr` only outputs the count.

How would I go about getting the weight value I need from the ComboBox?

Comment: You should use a multicolumn combobox instead. That would make your life a lot easier. Then you can just use an array with your AddItem, and use the List(row, col) property to retrieve each piece of data you want from the selected item.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30455382/excel-vba-inserting-values-into-multicolumn-combobox

Comment: You can also create a dynamic array of the literal values. Then, based on the index of combo item index return value from your array.

Comment: @braX Unfortunately the environment I'm programming in has a limited amount of ActiveX objects, and I don't have that option.

Comment: I dont think you understand. It's the same combobox. All comboboxes have that ability.

Comment: Look at the property box with combobox selected. See how it has a `ColumnCount` property?

Comment: You, learn something new everyday! @braX

Comment: @braX So to populate the single combobox I did it the way showed with the loop, how can I modify it for the 2 columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the multicolumn comobobox part of the question:

Use an array for AddItem (put it in a loop if you want)

```
  Dim Arr(0 To 1) As String
  Arr(0) = "Col 1"
  Arr(1) = "Col 2"
  cmb.AddItem Arr
```

and to retrieve data for the selected item:

```
cmb.List(cmb.ListIndex, 1)
```

you can also set up an enumeration for your column numbers like this:

```
Enum ColList
  Loc=0
  Weight=1
End Enum
```

then to retrieve data it would look like this (much more readable code)

```
cmb.List(cmb.ListIndex, ColList.Weight)
```

also, you dont have to use the word Fields... you can address your recordset like this:

```
rsDB1!Weight
```

Answer (score 0):

split string into an array (zero based)

```
 debug.print split("Loc: abc Weight : 1234"," ")(4)  ' the second argument is the separator character

 debug.print split("Loc: abc Weight : 1234")(4)      ' space is the default separator
```

both print 1234