# Keep duplicates but distinguish them

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, userform

I got pretty simple question. I will simplify the example. I got excel sheet with 2 columns. In the first column I want to keep duplicated items, lets say 'apple' . But in another column they differ, lets say 'green', 'red' etc.

I have userform with combobox and textbox. Combobox is related to column with apples, textbox to that with different values - colors. And when I choose item in Combobox it will show relevant value in textbox. But every time I choose `Apple` in combobox, it will show only the last option - `red` in this case.

Is There a way to treat this?

Those items in column A need to be the same, it can't be `apple1`, `apple2` etc.

And There will be more items in A columns and all can be duplicates, like `apple`, `apple`, `pear`, `orange`, `orange`, `orange` ...

It's terrible example but I Hope it makes sense

Pls help :)

```
Private Sub Userform_click() 
Dim fruit As String
Dim color As String

row_number = 1

Do

fruit = Sheets("List1").Range("A" & row_number)
color = Sheets("List1").Range("B" & row_number)

If ComboBox1 = fruit Then
    TextBox1 = color
End If

row_number = row_number + 1

Loop Until fruit = ""

End Sub



Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim fruit As String

row_number = 2

With ComboBox1
    .Clear
End With

Do

fruit = Sheets("List1").Range("A" & row_number)

If fruit <> "" Then
    With ComboBox1
        .AddItem fruit
    End With
End If

row_number = row_number + 1

Loop Until fruit = ""

End Sub
```

It is just a simple example.

Everytime I search for this I find only 'how to remove duplicates' :(.

EDIT:

OK guys one more thing, here is a picture attached where is stated what I want to do (again), but could you please send me complete code (if it is not too complicated?). I still can't figure it out. (Newbie)

CODE:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim fruit As String
Dim number As String

row_number = 1

With ComboBox1
    .Clear
End With

Do

number = Sheets("List1").Range("A" & row_number)
fruit = Sheets("List1").Range("B" & row_number)

If TextBox1 = number Then
    With ComboBox1
        .AddItem fruit
    End With
End If

row_number = row_number + 1

Loop Until fruit = ""

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim fruit As String
Dim fshape As String
Dim fcolor As String

row_number = 1

Do

fruit = Sheets("List1").Range("B" & row_number)
fshape = Sheets("List1").Range("C" & row_number)
fcolor = Sheets("List1").Range("D" & row_number)

If ComboBox1 = fruit Then
    TextBox2 = fshape
    TextBox3 = fcolor
End If

row_number = row_number + 1

Loop Until fruit = ""

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show your code. How do you fill the combo box? How do you get the value for the text box? Probably reading [mcve] will help you to improve your question.

Comment: Make use of `AutoFilter` to get the rows needed for your `ComboBox`, but as mentioned above by @Pᴇʜ, without your current code and how you get your values, it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: Sorry, the code for this part is that simple, that I didn't realitě is that important, and also I'm on my Phone, because computer is not online :) but I will Edit that

Comment: @Majkl You must use a multi column combo box and fill the text box from the second column of the combo box. Otherwise you cannot distinguish "Apple" from "Apple". See [Inserting values into multicolumn combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30455382/excel-vba-inserting-values-into-multicolumn-combobox) • Since you didn't show how you fill your combobox (see my comment before) we cannot help on that more detailed.

Comment: I know, Im working on it :) but it's terrible on Phone :D

Comment: Sorry took mě a while but I Hope it works now :)

Comment: Sorry for bothering again, I edited the question, so please could you look at it one more time and show me how to use those multicolumn comboboxes (again). Thanx :)

Comment: Have you actually followed/tried the link provided by @Pᴇʜ? Also both other answers provide clues on how you could tackle this. We are not here to do all the work for you I'm afraid =)

Comment: @Majkl see my edited answer for an esay way to fill data into the combobox. Otherwise use the information in the first link of my answer. If you got stuck or errors open up a new question and post the code you have tried.

Comment: Yeah sorry guys, I didn't wanted to Edit this question since it already has right answer. I wanted to ask via some private message or whatever but I found out that it is not allowed here and also right after I edited the question I received some 'chat option' which I didn't have before so I did what I did :).

Comment: Thing is that my real code (not related to fruit :D) has literally hundreds of textboxes and comboboxes and it is far from being perfect, so I didn't want to bother you with that code, since you would probably recommend me to delete it and start over :). I definitely want to improve it all one Day but for now I'm just trying to find out what can and what can't be Done. So I just wanted to know how to implement that multicolumn combobox to the code I provided with that Edit :) I'll check it all tomorrow. :) Thx

Comment: *"I want to improve it all one Day"* **That's the wrong approach.** The longer you wait, the more you will have to improve one day. The quicker you begin to improve it the earlier you will have an easier life because maintaining your your code will become esier. • I often see people doing it quick'n'dirty first, just to improve it later (or even never improve it). But what they don't see is that they will have to do the work double and additionally the quick'n'dirty is in most cases just dirty but not quick because they produce a mess with a lot of errors they have to find in that mess.

Comment: … Going clean from the very beginning following a good coding practice is the actually real quick approach (even if it doesn't look like). Because clean code has less errors, and if there is one you can easily find it (in a messy code it takes you hours). • Start writing good clean code *today*!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a multi column combo box and fill the text box from the second column of the combo box. Otherwise you cannot distinguish `Apple` from `Apple`.

See [Inserting values into multicolumn combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30455382/excel-vba-inserting-values-into-multicolumn-combobox) for more details about how to fill a multi column box.

Use the following code to fill the text box from the combo box selection:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Me.TextBox1.Text = Me.ComboBox1.List(Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex, 1)
End Sub
```

[image]

If you want the second column being invisible just set its width to `0`.

Another easy way to fill your ComboBox is to use the [RowSource property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/rowsource-property):

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim DataRange As Range
    Set DataRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:D7")

    With Me.ComboBox1
        .RowSource = DataRange.Address
        .ColumnCount = 4
        .ColumnWidths = "40;50;50;100"
        .ColumnHeads = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Note that the value of the ComboBox will automatically be the first column of your data. If you need to change it re-order your data columns.

Comment: Yes maybe this is the best solution, thanks for the nice visualization :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very simple example on how you could tackle the issue. I would suggest using a `ComboBox` for the category (Apple, Pear, Orange) and a `ListBox` for it's different products.

***Example data like:***

[image]

***Userform Like:***

[image]

***Code Like:***

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.ComboBox1.List = Array("Apple", "Pear")
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

With Sheet1 'Change according to your own sheets CodeName.
    Dim lr As Long: lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim cl As Range, rng As Range: Set rng = .Range("A1:B" & lr)
    rng.AutoFilter 1, Me.ComboBox1.Value
    Dim arr As Variant: arr = rng.Columns(2).Offset(1).Resize(rng.Columns(2).Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Me.ListBox1.List = arr
    rng.AutoFilter
    Me.TextBox1.Value = ""
End With

End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    Me.TextBox1.Value = Me.ListBox1.Value
End Sub
```

***Result:***

[image]
[image]

---

The way you currently try to work is quite inefficient, but below is how you could tackle that way too (however @Peh his proposal is more efficient)

***Other type of UserForm:***

[image]

New code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

With 'Change according to your sheets CodeName
    Dim lr As Long: lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim arr As Variant: arr = .Range("A2:A" & lr)
    Me.ComboBox1.List = arr
End With

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

With Sheet1 'Change according to your sheets CodeName
    Me.TextBox1.Value = .Cells(Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex - 1, 2).Value
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes that looks good and works fine, but I know it might not make sense here, but I want to show only one "color" at time. So "blindly" choose second "pear" and it will only show "blue", when I choose third "pear" it will show only "red" etc. That's why I used textbox :).

Comment: @Majkl As I said before: Therefore you must use a multi column combo box where the first column lists the fruit names and the second its color. Otherwise you cannot distinguish them.

Comment: Ok thank you a lot, maybe I will consider listbox, I'm gonna think about it, but thanks for the effort anyway :)

Comment: @Majkl, I've edited the answer with another section to show you how you could approach the direction you are heading. However as Peh mentioned, how do you feel you are going to distinquish between the same type of categories? As it is now, I highly recommend to rethink your approach.

Answer (score 2):

you could stay with a single column combo box, too

here's the whole code in your Userform code pane:

```
Option Explicit

Dim fruits As Variant, colors As Variant

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    If Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex <> -1 Then Me.TextBox1.Value = colors(Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex + 1, 1)
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Sheets("List1")
        With .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
            fruits = .Value
            colors = .Offset(, 1).Value
        End With
    End With
    Me.ComboBox1.List = fruits
 End Sub
```

where you need no button to press as textbox gets filled at every combobox change