# VBA Multicolumn combo box with array

Tags: vba

I am very new to vba. currently I am using this array code to fill combox.

```
Dim list As Object
Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Set Rng = Sheet3.Range("A8", Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

For Each rCell In Rng.Cells
    If Not list.contains(rCell.Value) Then list.Add (rCell.Value)
Next rCell
Dim v
'Sort the ArrayList object:
list.Sort
Sheet1.ComboBox1.list = list.ToArray()

Set list = Nothing
End Sub
```

I want to add Multi column to this combobox. The data is in B column. Can anyone help me on this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel VBA - inserting values into multicolumn combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30455382/excel-vba-inserting-values-into-multicolumn-combobox)

Comment: You need to be a bit clearer on your source data - you want to fill a *multi column* `ComboBox` but your source data is a single column - How do you intend to fill the multi columns?

Comment: Do you want putting a range from one column (B:B) in a multicolumn combo box? If yes, based on what to split the data in the range? And based on what to filter the array? If not, what do you want, in fact?