# Reference Column Value in Excel to Add Value to Access Table using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

My company uses Access for our project data, but most employees are only comfortable with Excel, so my manager gave me a project to create an Excel spreadsheet that looks similar to one of our forms that can update the Access database. I have limited VB experience from over a decade ago, so I'm now stuck on trying to figure out subs/functions to handle two columns where I need to:

1. using cell value from any given cell in the Mfg column on the Main
   sheet, look up matching value in Initial column of Manufacturer sheet
2. post value from ID column on Manufacturer sheet corresponding to
   Initial column value from previous step to Access table

I need to know the best way to perform this task twice (since values in two of my columns need to be "translated"/matched this way), as well as how to combine with my existing subroutine below that already handles posting the rest of the values properly to Access -- you'll find I currently have two lines referencing the fields that this needs to be done for that are commented out with *'fields referencing other Excel sheets* that haven't completely been filled out yet.

```
Option Explicit
Const AccessConStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=I:\LIBRARY\App\Project DB Development\IWC ProjAdmin DB AzureDevelopment Dash Update.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"

Public DBConn As ADODB.Connection
Public Proj As ADODB.Recordset 

Sub MattWriteNewData()

    OpenDBConn
    
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN")
    
    GetProj Sht.Range("ProjNum"), Sht.Range("ProjName")

            If MsgBox("Project Found: " & Proj!IDNum & ", " & Proj!Proj_Name & ", is this the correct project?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
            
            Sht.Range("ProjID") = Proj!ID
    
    Dim Dash As New ADODB.Recordset
        Dash.Open "dbo_Proj_Dash", DBConn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
        
    Dim i As Integer
        
        For i = 4 To 1000 'i = first row number, set the upper limit of rows and test at each row for data
            
            If Sht.Cells(i, 2) <> "" Then
                Dash.AddNew
                Dash!Dash_Num = Sht.Cells(i, 2)

                Dash!ID_Num = Proj!IDNum & "-" & Sht.Cells(i, 2) 'reference dbo_Proj for "IDNum"/project number, reference Dash # column in Excel for dash number
                Dash!Proj_ID = Proj!ID
                Dash!Act = 1
                Dash!Proj_IDNum = Proj!IDNum 'set to dbo_Proj for "IDNum"
            Else
                GoTo Out
            End If
            
            If Sht.Cells(i, 3) <> "" Then
                Dash!Dash_Desc = Sht.Cells(i, 3)
            Else
                MsgBox ("Dash " & Sht.Cells(i, 2) & ", on row " & i & " is missing a description. This row will be skipped")
                GoTo Out
            End If
            
                
            If Sht.Cells(i, 4) <> "" Then Dash!Dash_Qty = Sht.Cells(i, 4)
            If Sht.Cells(i, 5) <> "" Then Dash!Dash_Unit = Sht.Cells(i, 5)
            
            'fields referencing other Excel sheets
            If Sht.Cells(i, 6) <> "" Then Dash!Mfg = "" 'tbd
            If Sht.Cells(i, 7) <> "" Then Dash!Dwg_Draftsman = "" 'tbd
            
            If Sht.Cells(i, 8) <> "" Then Dash!Date_TargetSubmit = Sht.Cells(i, 8)
            If Sht.Cells(i, 9) <> "" Then Dash!Date_ActualSubmit = Sht.Cells(i, 9)
            If Sht.Cells(i, 10) <> "" Then Dash!Date_TargetApprove = Sht.Cells(i, 10)
            If Sht.Cells(i, 11) <> "" Then Dash!Date_ActualApprove = Sht.Cells(i, 11)
            If Sht.Cells(i, 12) <> "" Then Dash!Date_TargetRLSMfr = Sht.Cells(i, 12)
            If Sht.Cells(i, 13) <> "" Then Dash!Date_ActualRlsMfr = Sht.Cells(i, 13)
            If Sht.Cells(i, 14) <> "" Then Dash!Date_TargetShip = Sht.Cells(i, 14)
            If Sht.Cells(i, 15) <> "" Then Dash!Date_ActualShip = Sht.Cells(i, 15)
            If Sht.Cells(i, 16) <> "" Then Dash!Date_TargetInstallFinish = Sht.Cells(i, 16)
            If Sht.Cells(i, 17) <> "" Then Dash!Date_TargetInstallFinish = Sht.Cells(i, 17)
            
            If Sht.Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
                If TestDash(Sht.Cells(i, 1), Dash!Dash_Num, Dash!Dash_Desc) = True Then
                    GoTo Out
                Else
                    Sht.Cells(i, 1) = ""
            End If
            End If
    
        Dash.Update

        Sht.Cells(i, 1) = Dash!ID

Out:
        Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds like you need either VLOOKUP or Match + Index, but there's not much to go on here...

Comment: "only comfortable with Excel" - sounds like employees are running the company. Boss should be convinced that an Access GUI is in best interest of company and tell employees to learn. It's not like they have to build it, just get used to a different interface, which won't take long. Are you building a user form in Excel? Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30455382/excel-vba-inserting-values-into-multicolumn-combobox

Comment: @June7 I'm not really using any of the form-building tools in Excel, if that's what you're wondering -- however, I have set formatting and, for some columns, either set up a drop down menu or date picker to restrict inputs. No combo boxes, data entry forms, etc.

Comment: I once inherited a partially built db that used Excel as frontend. After 3 months I made decision to eliminate Excel component. Everyone was happier. I know your situation is different but I do believe in the long term, it would better serve company. So employees know Excel, they can get to know Access interface. It's not like they never had to learn something new before.

Comment: @June7 That's fine, but I'm not a decisionmaker/influencer, so even if I agreed with you, it's not going to happen. My manager has been here for almost 30 years and I'm actually the only official IT person who works in this company -- my manager is actually an engineering manager who just seems to pick up programming fairly easily. If he could've gotten everyone to use Access, I'm sure he would've done so years ago, but I know upper management is very hesitant to force anyone to learn anything extra of a technical nature.

Comment: It's not like they have to learn that much. Everyone has filled out on-line forms before. However, you have ideas from Tim Williams that will give you something to start with. Possibly build VLookup in worksheet and code references column with VLookup output. Although, could probably build an Access form to demo in the time it will take to figure out this Excel code.

Comment: @June7 I've built Access forms before. This Excel "form" I'm creating is in addition to that. I was told this is task is to simplify the work for the PMs and to learn more about VBA/programming.

Thanks for sharing your opinion on how much learning this may/may not be for others, but it still won't change the fact that the users you think should learn access for the benefit of the company will NEVER be asked to AND that I STILL have to perform this task. I still have to (re-)learn and expand my skill set for programming as a part of MY role.

Comment: Core of my point is users don't really have to learn Access. They already have keyboarding skills. All they would have to do is fill in a form. But 'nuff said. Wish you luck.

Comment: @TimWilliams I think INDEX + MATCH will be the way I need to go, since the lookup on both sheets would need to reference a value in a column to the left of it.

Hope this is a better explanation of the process I need to code:
-Sheet 1, Column Mfg contains values in text format.
-Sheet 2 is basically just a table with columns ID, Desc, and Init in order from left to right. Column Init is a list of all the possible values for Column Mfg on Sheet Main.
-For each value in Column Mfg, I need the value in ID to post to an Access table field (the two lines below commented section in recordset)

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a lookup function:

```vb
Function InitialToManufId(inits)
    Dim m, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Manufacturer")
    m = Application.Match(inits, ws.Columns("D"), 0) 'for example
    If Not IsError(m) Then
        InitialToManufId = ws.Columns("B").Cells(m).Value 'eg
    Else
        InitialToManufId = "" 'or something else, if not matched
    End If
End Function
```

Then something like:

```vb
With Sht.Cells(i, 6) 
    If Len(.Value) >0 Then Dash!Mfg = InitialToManufId(.Value)
End with
```